# Add Field NoteID for Rest API

Tags: acumatica

In acumatica, the ID Row is an entity persistent for REST API only for table with the Field NoteID.
It's possible to add NoteID for dac without this field.

Do you think it's the best way ? (example for the POVendorInventory)

In SQL Script

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sys.columns 
          WHERE Name = N'NoteID'
          AND Object_ID = Object_ID(N'POVendorInventory'))
BEGIN
    ALTER TABLE POVendorInventory ADD NoteID uniqueidentifier 
END
```

In the description

```
#region NoteID
public abstract class noteID : PX.Data.IBqlField { }
protected Guid? _NoteID;
[PXNote()]
public virtual Guid? NoteID { get; set; }
#endregion
```

Comment: The DAC extension looks fine, but I would use the Database scripts option to add a column of the Customization package instead of using a direct SQL script.

Comment: Samvel, I tried but it created a usr field. I really need the NoteID field and not UsrNoteID

Comment: There is a way to adjust the name of the field after that usr prefix is added. You can do that from the Edit Project Items actions. This package publishes fine for me in the preview of 23R1. https://1drv.ms/u/s!Aoc7WBv5CbzIiUpBudsRLocnvVmQ?e=1QLPUa

Comment: Thanks Samvel. In 2022R1, it's not possible, after acumatica update, the field was deleted. I will wait the 23R1 with your option :)